# Java parallel streams slower with reduce?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I'm testing parallel streams and I've found this strange (to me) result. In my test:

```
final int MIL = 1000000;
IntStream s;

s = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, MIL);    
long start = System.nanoTime();
s.filter(i -> i % 11 == 0)
    .map(i -> i % 3)
    .reduce(0, (subtotal, element) -> subtotal + element);
long end = System.nanoTime();

System.out.println("NON PARALLEL reduce: " + (end - start));

s = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, MIL);
long startP = System.nanoTime();
s.parallel().filter(i -> i % 11 == 0)
    .map(i -> i % 3)
    .reduce(0, (subtotal, i) -> subtotal + i);
long endP = System.nanoTime();

System.out.println("    PARALLEL reduce: " + (endP - startP));
```

I get the following result:

```
NON PARALLEL reduce: 10156400
    PARALLEL reduce: 31094100
```

that is the parallel stream **is considerably slower**. Why?
If I susbstitute *reduce()* with *sorted()*, the result is opposite: parallel stream is significantly faster.

Comment: Have you compared the speed for different range sizes. A few additional data points will most likely show that at larger ranges, parallelisation will win in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Running your code on my 8(4) cores CPU, parallel is faster by 25-35%.
Parallel functioning behind the scenes is a multithreading.
Initializing and synchronizing threads are time efficient.
Speed belongs to what do you do with your stream data, and also your CPU on what you runs the code.